# Rails to Render JSON with Newly Calculated Value for Each Element of a Rendered Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I want to add a newly calculated value to each element of a collection that is rendered as `render json:` when a *Rails API route* is queried.

This is the current set up:

```rb
# app/Models

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pools, through: :user_pool
end

class Pool < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users, through: :user_pool
    has_many :stakes

    def average()
        some_kind_of_average(self.stakes)
    end
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/pool_controller.rb

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @pools = @user.pools
    render json: @pools, only: [:ticker, :id]
  end
```

What I would like to do is to add for each `pool` of the `@pools` collection a value of `pool.average`.

it should be something like this:

```rb
# app/controllers/pool_controller.rb

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @pools = @user.pools
    render json: @pools, only: [:ticker, :id, average: @pools.each {|pool| pool.average}]
  end
```

Of course the above doesn't work, what is the most elegant way to achieve my goal?

The only way I can think of is to calculate all of the average prior queries, and just insert it in the database as a new attribute of `Pool`, so that the controller would simply become:

```rb
# app/controllers/pool_controller.rb

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @pools = @user.pools
    render json: @pools, only: [:ticker, :id, :average]
  end
```

But I am wondering how would I do it if I want to avoid a mass calculation to update the database adding and :average attribute to every pool. Even though perhaps is the best solution rather than calculating averages for each query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in pool.rb write a method called average and in that method write the logic,

in the index method of controller write this way

```rb
render json: @pools, only: [:ticker, :id, :average], methods: :average
```